# Bash: Retrieving and comparing two dates

Tags: bash

In Bash script, I would like to compare two dates and if one is greater than the other, carry out a task.

Two dates that I'm comparing are:

svn repo's last change date, I get the date info like so:

```
svn info svn://server.com/reponame -r 'HEAD' | grep 'Last Changed Date'
```

It gives me something like this:

```
Last Changed Date: 2011-06-06 22:26:50 -0400 (Mon, 06 Jun 2011)
```

Then I'm finding the date information of the most current backup file in the directory, like so:

```
ls -lt --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" | head -n 2 | tail -n 1
```

(I wonder if there is a better way to do it with out both head and tail above)

Which gives me something like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 user1 14 2011-06-09 07:52:50 svn.dump
```

What I would like to do next, is to retrieve date from first output and compare it with second output date and if one is greater than the other one, I will do an svn dump. what would be the most appropriate way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: No time for pondering the date comparison stuff (I usually use Perl and its Date::Manip module), but a quick note about ls replacement: how about `stat -c "%y" svn.dump`, or if you truly want to mimic ls output, `stat -c "%A %U %G %h %y %n" svn.dump`

Comment: Stat seems like a function I would want to use, stat -c "%X" svn dump gives me seconds. Now if I could get the last modified date from svn in seconds...

Answer (score 4):

/bin/date can convert time to formats, including seconds from epoch.

```
DATE_1="`svn info svn://server.com/reponame -r 'HEAD' | grep 'Last Changed Date' | grep -E -o \"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\"`"

DATE_2="`ls -lt --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | grep -E -o \"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\"`"

if [ "`date --date \"$DATE_1\" +%s`" -gt "`date --date \"$DATE_2\" +%s`" ]; then
    echo "Greater"
else
    echo "Less or equal"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for not forgetting how to convert the svn date to a comparable date  like I did :)

Answer (score 2):

```
## Specify the filename to dump here
_filename = svn.dump

## Grab the mtime of the file and print out in "seconds since Epoch format"
_fileepoch=$(find ${_filename} -printf "%Ts")

## Grab the last changed date of the file and store it in _svndate
_svndate=$(svn info svn://server.com/reponame -r 'HEAD' \
              | grep 'Last Changed Date' \
              | awk '{print $4, $5, $6}')

## Use date --date with the "%s" format specifier to print seconds since Epoch
## for that date
_svnepoch=$(date --date "${_svndate}" "+%s")
```

You should be able to compare `${_svnepoch}` and `${_fileepoch}` now

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply compare on number of seconds since the epoch `ls -lt --time-style="+%s"`. That gives you a nice number you can compare on.

From `man bash`

> ```
>    arg1 OP arg2
>           OP  is  one  of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
>           These arithmetic binary operators return true if
>           arg1 is equal to, not equal to, less than, less
>           than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or
>           equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2 may be
>           positive or negative integers.
> ```

Easy enough to do.

```
F1=$(ls -l --time-style='+%s' file1|awk '{ print $6 }')
F2=$(ls -l --time-style='+%s' file2|awk '{ print $6 }')
if [ $F1 -gt $F2 ]; then
    echo yay
    echo F1: $F1
else
    echo nay
    echo F2: $F2
fi
```

As others have posted, a scripting language that actually gives meaning to a date probably is better suited for these kind of tasks